# Modules to set credits/points

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a module to allow myself or other moderators to set credits/points for each site member. The site members can use the credits to purchase items in the store.  I don't want to use any real world currency for the transactions, just virtual points.

This site is for an online guild. My hope is to set up a reward system and give each member points for being active in the guild, they can turn around and use the points to get content for their characters in game.

Is there any module that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a google search and found the [Commerce Credits](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_credits) module; it sounds like what you're looking to do.

> Commerce Credits allows you to have users buy or win credits. The credits these users buy or win are fully configurable and can expire after some time. The process used for these credits is also fully configurable through Rules. It allows you to entirely define your own process for the payment and the use of these credits.